# how to  get .jasper and .bak and also view direct excel in iReport 2.0.2

Tags: jasper-reports

I have problems to view report. first, when I try to click view button on the excel button in 'build'. it not view out the report but it is just generate excel files in a folder only. Secondly, Can I get the file .Jasper and .bak  after I view the report.

The main problem is when i want to view direct my report for excel. The error show:-

```
  Exporting XLS to file (using POI)... .\senarai_cpp_4(1)_tnsparthis_pembaharuanPenangguhan.xls.
Error exporting print... Sheet name cannot be blank, greater than 31 chars, or contain any of /\*?[] 
Can't find the translation for key = iReportCompiler.errorExportingPrint: using default (Error exporting print... {0} )  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Sheet name cannot be blank, greater than 31 chars, or contain any of /\*?[]      at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.BoundSheetRecord.setSheetname(BoundSheetRecord.java:162)      at org.apache.poi.hssf.model.Workbook.setSheetName(Workbook.java:464)      at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.createSheet(HSSFWorkbook.java:540)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsExporter.createSheet(JRXlsExporter.java:147)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReportToStream(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:393)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRXlsAbstractExporter.exportReport(JRXlsAbstractExporter.java:221)      at it.businesslogic.ireport.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:1329)      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  
Export running time: 1,212
```

Comment: i have update my question, i just ask about how to view the excel report after i click the preview button. why the report not view the report?

Comment: Are you talking about preview function in iReport?

Comment: yes.alex. i have problem with iReport 2.0.2. i don't know why all my report can't view direct when i click the preview button especially when i want to run excel files.

Comment: It's very old version. May be it is a bug. Did you try to do the same operation on the another PC? May be the installation is broken

Comment: i have update my question.i have try for another pc but the problem still same.i also have uninstall and install again the software but it situation still same.:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The old version of iReport uses an outdated version of POI. The library doesn't have the ability to truncate sheet names for excel. The solution is to rename you report (jrxml) to have a short filename.

You can change the location of the backup file by going into Tools -> Options.